# LateInitializationError: Field '_chewieController' has not been initialized in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am have issues with my my video-player all issue lead to this point but I don't know what to do once I click on the play button I get this error please I need help with the initialization

Reload already in progress, ignoring request
Restarted application in 1,023ms.

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following LateError was thrown building Video(dirty, state: _VideoState#4a5db):
LateInitializationError: Field '_chewieController@50055179' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was
Video
package:goodwork/allscreens/videoplayer.dart:69
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _VideoState._chewieController (package:goodwork/allscreens/videoplayer.dart)
package:goodwork/allscreens/videoplayer.dart:1

[`enter image description here`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRKIp.jpg)

```
           import 'package:chewie/chewie.dart';
      import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
      import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

      class Video extends StatefulWidget {
      final VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;
    final bool loop;
    Video({
   required this.videoPlayerController,
   required this.loop,
   Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoState createState() => _VideoState();
}

   class _VideoState extends State<Video> {
  late ChewieController _chewieController;
 @override
 void iniState() {
   super.initState();
   _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: widget.videoPlayerController,
    looping: widget.loop,
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    autoInitialize: true);
   }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Chewie(
  controller: _chewieController,
    );
  }

  @override
 void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
      widget.videoPlayerController.dispose();
   _chewieController.dispose();
    }
  }

   class Videoplayers extends StatefulWidget {
   final String videodata;
    Videoplayers({required this.videodata});

  @override
 _VideoplayersState createState() => _VideoplayersState();
 }

  class _VideoplayersState extends State<Videoplayers> {
    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      title: const Text(
        "Video Player",
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
      ),
      leading: const Image(
        image: AssetImage("images/logo.png"),
      )),
      body: Center(
      child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Video(
        loop: true,
        videoPlayerController:
            VideoPlayerController.network(widget.videodata),
        ),
        ),
     ),
   );
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `iniState` instead of `initState`. And after correcting *Restart* the app, not *Reload*.

Comment: Silly me thanks allot ...it works now

Comment: @DevelkinsTarget If you solved your issue, please select this answer as the correct one.